# UItableView with UItextfield and animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode3.2

after a lot of trial and error, I'm giving up and asking the question. I've seen a lot of people with similar problems but can't get all the answers to work right.

I have a UITableView in which i have 35 textfiled one below the other.

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the UITableView, I can't manage to get my cells properly positioned above the keyboard.

I have seen many answers talking about changing view sizes,etc... but none of them has worked nicely so far.

Could anybody clarify the "right" way to do this with a concrete code example?

following is my .m file:

```
#import "EditProfilePage.h"


@implementation EditProfilePage
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 70.0


static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;

static const CGFloat CELL_HEIGHT = 44;

static const CGFloat TOOLBAR_HEIGHT = 44;
static const CGFloat WINDOW_MINUS_TOOLBAR_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT = 460;



@synthesize scrollView,tableContents,txtField,allTextField,tableView;

@synthesize  txtUserName ,txtFirstName ,txtLastName ,txtNickName,txtDisplayName,txtEmail,txtWebSite,txtAboutMe ,txtNewPassword ,txtPasswordAgain,btnSubmit ;

//extended profile information
@synthesize txtPayPalEmail ,txtActiveMemPk ,txtMemPkExpireDate,lbl,textFieldBeingEdited;

//business profile information
@synthesize txtBusinessName ,txtAbnAcn ,txtContactName ,txtPhone ,txtFax ,txtMobile ,txtBusinessEmail ,txtFacebookLink ,txtLinkedinLink ,txtMySpaceLink;
@synthesize txtBlogLink ,txtInstanMessage ,txtWebsite ,txtStreet ,txtCitySuburb ,txtZipCode ,txtState ,txtTradingHour;
@synthesize  txtActiveOfService ,txtTradeOnWeekend ,txtProduct , txtService ,txtPickUpAndDelivery;




- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    allTextField=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",@"",nil];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (CELL_HEIGHT * [self.allTextField count]))];
    ![enter image description here][1][self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, (CELL_HEIGHT * [self.allTextField count]))];



}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
     object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
     object:nil];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}
//
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]; 
        //self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
}


-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
   // keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
//    if (keyboardIsShowing == NO)
    {
        //keyboardIsShowing = YES;
//        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
//        frame.size.height -= keyboardHeight;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        //self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect frame = textField.frame;
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    if (textField == txtUserName.tag)
    {
        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * txtUserName.tag;
    }
   // else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_TWO])
//    {
//        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_TWO;
//    }
//    else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_THREE])
//    {
//        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_THREE;
//    }
//    else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_FOUR])
//    {
//        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_FOUR;
//    }
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.tableView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat halfHeight = viewHeight / 2;
    CGFloat midpoint = frame.origin.y + (textField.frame.size.height / 2);
    if (midpoint < halfHeight)
    {
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size.height = midpoint;
    }
    else
    {
        frame.origin.y = midpoint;
        frame.size.height = midpoint;
    }
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //  NSArray *lstData=[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.txtField objectAtIndex:section]];
    //  return[lstData count];

    return[allTextField count];
}




-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    }

    if ([indexPath row]==0)
    {
        txtUserName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtUserName.placeholder=@"User Name";
        //txtUserName.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [txtUserName addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        cell.accessoryView=txtUserName;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"User Name:";
        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

        txtUserName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        txtUserName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtUserName.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
        txtUserName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        // (The tag by indexPath.row is the critical part to identifying the appropriate
        // row in textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldShouldEndEditing below:)

        txtUserName.tag=indexPath.row;

        //txtUserName.delegate = self;

        txtUserName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        [txtUserName setEnabled: YES];

        [cell addSubview:txtUserName];

        [txtUserName release];



        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"impact" size:10 line:2];

    }

    if ([indexPath row]==1)
    {
        txtFirstName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtFirstName.placeholder=@"First Name";
        cell.accessoryView=txtFirstName;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"First Name:";
        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];

    }

    if ([indexPath row]==2)
    {
        txtLastName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtLastName.placeholder=@"Last Name";
        cell.accessoryView=txtLastName;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Last Name:";
        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


    }

    if ([indexPath row]==3)
    {
        txtNickName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtNickName.placeholder=@"Nick Name";
        cell.accessoryView=txtNickName;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Nick Name:";
        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


    }

    if ([indexPath row]==4)
    {
        txtDisplayName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtDisplayName.placeholder=@"Display Name";
        cell.accessoryView=txtDisplayName;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Display Name:";
        //cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


    }

    if ([indexPath row]==5)
    {
        txtEmail=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,25)];
        txtEmail.placeholder=@"Email";
        cell.accessoryView=txtEmail;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Email ID:";
        cell.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


    }



    return cell;
}







@end
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the problem is.  Try to reproduce the problem with a smaller code sample.

Comment: i have 35 textfield on tableview one below the other .....i want to move textfield up when ever user touches the texfield over the keyboard.... plz help me out.....thank's sir

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide us with a screen shot so that we can fully understand the problem.  To reiterate, shorten the code until you have the smallest possible amount of code that still reproduces the problem, and edit your question using the new code and screen shot.

Comment: i tried to upload the screen short... jst check that page ...thank's sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the scroll view taller so that you can scroll the lower text fields above the keyboard.

Here's an article that explains how to do it:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/adjust-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard.html

Comment: i had try that earlier but it's not working...can u plz provide me other tutorial